# How I can submit my jquery steps form to a PHP file?

Tags: php, submit, jquery-steps

I have created a form via jquery steps and a lot of inputfields. But if I click on "Finish" - then nothing happens. How I can submit the entries(values) of the form via POST to my form.php page?

Would be great if Someone Here can help me.

Thank you all and have a happy new year.

Jay

Comment: [Why is *“Can someone help me?”* not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have all inputs fields in `<form></form>`

Please add code to the your question please for better understanding of your problem..